# Luck of certainty

Tags: metaphysics, terminology, cosmology

Title may be bit confusing but let me explain.

Our existence depends on very small possibilities as a person and as humanity. 
There are billions of planets without any living thing but there is life on Earth and we consider ourselves lucky.

Similar to birth of humans. There are millions of spermatozoon but one of those form us.And we again consider ourselves lucky.

Do you think this situation can be regard as **luck** since everyone can think about existence of own actually have to be exists and its impossible to think about unluckiness of nihility (nonexistence) ?

Comment: See [Cosmological argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmological_argument) and [Anthropic principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthropic_principle).

Comment: No, it wasn't luck. Our existence was determined by God.

Comment: Do you have any proof ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I think the answer depends on you. By the way, I wouldn't define a priori "luck" the fact that you are born, that we all are born, because this is a remnant left by the christian belief that life is a gift granted by god. How can one establish if all our lives are, or were, worth living? I'm inclined to think that some of us would be, or would have been, better of dead or unborn, while another part of us had had a great and joyful life. Maybe a better word is **accident**. Someone is the result of a "happy accident", someone not, and not for his fault, but just because we all are accidents, and this is hard to accept.

Answer (score 1):

I think luck is a subjective term.

Given that you exist, it is impossible to think of getting lucky. Because, anyone who WOULD be born would consider themselves lucky to be born. But since it is already given that you are born, no question of luck in this sentence arises.

As a sentient being however luck arises in your context when we ponder the question " Why was I born?". In that pursuit, you can certainly think of yourself as lucky. Because, given that you could or could not be born, that certainly is a lucky possibility.